# 01846. 00000 - "not a valid day of the week"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
updateDate ='Mon Mar 13 22:43:29 +0000 2017'
select length, 
       replace(updateDate,'+0000','') as fecha,
       TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         TO_DATE(
           replace(updateDate,'+0000 ',''),
           'DY  MON DD  HH24:MI:SS YYYY'
         ),
         '+00:00',
         '-05:00'
       ) as fechaCol
from   irregularities
```

I want to convert the string to format date, the updateDate and '+0000' are parameters of the table irregularities. Where is the mistake?

Comment: We don't know what the value of "updateDate" looks like.  PLease edit the question and add the details.

Comment: Ready, I asign the value to updateDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2119.htm#OLADM697):

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ (char-exp [, fmt [ 'nlsparam' ] ])
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>
> `char-exp`
>   A text expression that you wan to convert.
>
> `fmt`
>   Specifies the datetime format template to be used to convert the text expression. See Table 9-4, "Datetime Format Elements" for more information about the datetime format template.
>
> When you omit this argument, the function uses the default format of `TIMESTAMP_TZ` for the object.
>
> `nlsparam`
>   Specifies the language in which month and day names and abbreviations are returned. This argument can have this form:
>
> ```
> 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = language'
> ```
>
> If you omit this argument, then this function uses the default date language for your session.

`TO_DATE` returns a date data type and `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` expects a text expression for its first argument so Oracle will be "helpful" and perform an implicit conversion from a date back to text using `TO_CHAR` and will use your session's default date format (given by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter) so your query is effectively:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         TO_CHAR(
           TO_DATE(
             replace(updateDate,'+0000 ',''),
             'DY  MON DD  HH24:MI:SS YYYY'
           ),
           (SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
         ),
         '+00:00',
         '-05:00'
       ) as fechaCol
from   irregularities
```

It is this implicit conversion that is causing your error as the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and the format for `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` do not match.

**Solution**

You do not need to use `TO_DATE`. Just call `TO_TIMESTMAP_TZ` directly:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         updateDate
         'DY  MON DD  HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM YYYY',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'
       ) as fechaCol
from   irregularities
```

The `TZH` and `TZM` format models will read the time zone hours and minutes and set the timestamp to the appropriate time zone for the input.

It is unclear what your `+00:00` and `-05:00` arguments to the `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` function are meant to achieve (since the second argument should be the format model and the third the NLS parameters) but if you are trying to convert from one time zone to another then just use `AT TIME ZONE '-05:00'`.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
         updateDate
         'DY  MON DD  HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM YYYY',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'
       ) AT TIME ZONE '-05:00' as fechaCol
from   irregularities
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want:

```
to_timestamp_tz(updateDate,
  'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM YYYY'),
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
  at time zone '-05:00'
```

That converts the whole original string, including the time zone offset, to a time stamp with time zone - specifying that the day and month names are in English; and then gives you that value at the -5:00 time zone. Though you probably want to use a time zone region rather than an offset.

Demo:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with irregularities (updateDate) as (select 'Mon Mar 13 22:43:29 +0000 2017' from dual)
-- actual query
select 
    to_timestamp_tz(updateDate,
      'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM YYYY',
      'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
      at time zone '-05:00' as fechaCol
from 
    irregularities;

FECHACOL                            
------------------------------------
2017-03-13 17:43:29.000000000 -05:00
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=edea2a4f9565a0818ebdd065630fd595)